# Flex RichText shows Jagged text, sometimes

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I’m building an iPad app with Flex/CS3 in Flash Builder 4.7. Making an iPad app. However, when being tested some people started telling me that some screens have the RichText sparks elements showing text jagged, rather than smooth.

However, it only happens sometimes. If you go back to that screen the text looks fine. Any ideas why such a thing might be happening? Most of the time everything looks fine, both locally on my development machine as well as on the iPad app when it's being looked at on a tablet.

Comment: While I do not know the exact cause of this, it is worth noting that the `RichText` elements **are not** optimized for mobile. For text, you can use `Label`, `TextArea`, and `TextInput`, I believe. I generally use Label for nearly everything, though it does not offer rich text benefits, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you. The biggest thing for us has been ®† and other special characters and superscripts. Usually it works fine on the iPads tested so far. Not sure about other platforms.

Comment: Are you embedding your fonts? If not, you definitely want to be doing that (you should always embed fonts regardless)

Comment: you can also check if stage x and stage y of your reach text are integers(if not, text pixels will be blurred over real screen pixels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that under certain circumstances it was adding multiple rich text components with the exact same text in it over and over itself, meaning I'd have several layers of identical content that, when overlapped, made it look pixelated on most devices.

I've made the app be a little smarter and not add what's already there, and it's looks great. Thanks.